# I cant create file system under Users\Public with installer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, installation

I am trying to create a file system when installing a WPF application.  Currently I am creating the filesystem at run time.  I am able to use the FileSystem page in Visual Studio 2010 to create the filesystem I want in any folder except for Users\public.

In the installer Filsystem page I create a special folder, but I need to give my special folder a default location. I have already tried:
%SystemRoot%\Users\Public - it says it cant find it [Error: Cannot access network drive ...]
And the other built in options go to places I don't want the fiels to be, commonfiles/program files/user documents/etc.

Can someone help me with creating the file system under Users\Public?

The directory I want to create is C:\Users\Public\MY_FOLDER\MY_OTHER_FOLDERS...

Comment: Why are you set on users\public? Do you just need a directory to put data that all users have write access?

Comment: Its what is currently being used for the software I'm working on and they do not want to change the directory structure of a released product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `%SystemDrive%` rather than `%SystemRoot%`.  Check it with the Command Prompt.

```
C:\>set System
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
```

**EDIT:** To use environment variables in an MSI package, use the format `[%Name]`, so in your case `[%SystemDrive]`.

Reference: [Windows Installer Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/09/16/461742.aspx)

Comment: I tried both, it just tries to use "%SystemDrive% as part of the filesystem string instead of getting the drive.

Comment: THANKS! That got me into the directory!